# Convert file from csv to parquet on S3 with aws boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I wrote a script that would execute a query on Athena and load the result file in a specified aws boto S3 location.

```
import boto3
def run_query(query, database, s3_output):
    client = boto3.client('athena', region_name='my-region')
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': database
            },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': s3_output,
            }
        )
    print('Execution ID: ' + response['QueryExecutionId'])
    return response

query = """select ..."""

database = 'db_name'

path_template = 's3://bucket_name/path/version={}'

current_time =  str(datetime.datetime.now())

result = run_query(query, database, path_template.format(current_time))
```

It does work but the problem is that I have a csv file as the specified location. But I don't want a csv file I want a parquet file.

The only way I manage to obtain what I want is to download the file convert it with panda to parquet to reupload it.
It's annoying that  I can't just convert directly without fetching the file.

Anyone has another way to suggest ? I don't want to use a CTAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments of the @Istvan answer, @John Rotenstein suggested that I could do that with an INSERT INTO query.

https://aws.amazon.com/fr/about-aws/whats-new/2019/09/amazon-athena-adds-support-inserting-data-into-table-results-of-select-query/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a CTAS:

```
CREATE TABLE db.table_name
WITH (
    external_location = 's3://yourbucket/path/table_name',
    format = 'PARQUET',
    parquet_compression = 'GZIP',
    partitioned_by = ARRAY['dt']
)
AS
SELECT
    ...
;
```

This way the result of the select will be saved as Parquet.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html

> Use CTAS queries to:
>
> - Create tables from query results in one step, without repeatedly
>     querying raw data sets. This makes it easier to work with raw data
>     sets.
> - Transform query results into other storage formats, such as
>     Parquet and ORC. This improves query performance and reduces query
>     costs in Athena. For information, see Columnar Storage Formats.
> - Create
>     copies of existing tables that contain only the data you need.

UPDATE (2019.10):

AWS just released INSERT INTO for Athena.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html

> Inserts new rows into a destination table based on a SELECT query
>   statement that runs on a source table, or based on a set of VALUES
>   provided as part of the statement. When the source table is based on
>   underlying data in one format, such as CSV or JSON, and the
>   destination table is based on another format, such as Parquet or ORC,
>   you can use INSERT INTO queries to transform selected data into the
>   destination table's format.

There are some limitations:

> - INSERT INTO is not supported on bucketed tables. For more information, see Bucketing vs Partitioning.
> - When running an INSERT query on a table with underlying data that is encrypted in Amazon S3, the output files that the INSERT query writes are not encrypted by default. We recommend that you encrypt INSERT query results if you are inserting into tables with encrypted data. For more information about encrypting query results using the console, see Encrypting Query Results Stored in Amazon S3. To enable encryption using the AWS CLI or Athena API, use the EncryptionConfiguration properties of the StartQueryExecution action to specify Amazon S3 encryption options according to your requirements.

Comment: I don't want to use a CTAS

Comment: Let me know if you found another way.

Comment: sadly I don't think there is :(. Stackoverflow was my last ressort. Event the other example that claims doing just do what I'm currently doing.

Comment: Yep, there is no other way. I wrote a complete ETL pipeline to work around the lack of insert into and the fact that I cannot control the output of a query to be Parquet/ORC.

Comment: Do you know why they don't propose this feature ?

Comment: No idea, probably they make more money this way or there is a technical limitation how they set up the fork of Presto. This resulted in some client moving from Athena to Presto.

Comment: @RobertReynolds Why do you not wish to use a CTAS? I wonder if you could pre-create an (empty) output table as PARQUET, and then INSERT INTO using the query?

Comment: I tried that. It does work but not in my case in particular because of dumbly path design (they put illegal character in folder name that will coorespond to hive partition)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein there is no insert into. We solved this by CTASing into a temp table and copy the data over using S3 copy.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein funnily enough they just released insert into